# Install a windows executable using pip

Tags: python, pip

I have a go lang package which builds windows binary `.exe` file . but has a python wrapper on top of it to interact with Python Language

In case I have to perform something like `pip install somepackage`

#### Queries:

1.Whats the best practise to deal with this installable

2.Is it good idea to use `sitepackages` as the default destination or use `c:\python\` or to put it out seperately and add it to environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation around PIP to enable command line scripts is available          [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html)